# Ansible AWX EE and lineinfile module

Tags: ansible, k3s, ansible-awx

Heyall!

Im having some difficulty understanding a particular playbook that we are working on.

Simple scenario, we want to edit a file that is running on AWX itself, which is running on k3s. The playbook uses lineinfile module and we want to edit a particular file on the host itself located in /projects.

Playbook executes fine and says that line has been added however what we have noticed is that it looks like the VM is running on the EE pod which is created when using the execution environment. Case in point when we added the the backupflag in the playbook, during execution we have managed to see the backupfile created on the overlay volume. Then container is automatically removed and file is gone.

[root@infraawx WIN_Cluster]# locate WIN_Cluster.csv.
/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/541/fs/runner/project/WIN_Cluster/WIN_Cluster.csv.59.2022-05-18@10:54:28~

Playbook is

```
   - name: Adding initial line to spreadsheet
     ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
       remote_user: root
       path: '/projects/vmware/{{ cluster_name | replace(" ",replacer) + "/" + cluster_name | replace(" ",replacer)}}.csv'
       line: "Testing123"
       insertafter: EOF
       backup: yes
       create: yes
       state: present
     register: testout
     delegate_to: localhost
```

Any clues what might be happening?

Thank you!